# Eclipse server not publishing subprojects jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am trying to publish a web app in Eclipse using Tomcat, this was previously working before swapping to and from an older version of my codebase.

I am receiving an error when attempting to run the Tomcat server through Eclipse, it says it cannot find a file in the classpath for a referenced project within the workspace. When checking against another project I can see that in the lib folder for the project in ...metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ that the reference project is stored as a folder with .java files. On a PC where this is still working the projects are included as .jar files.

I've tried with a fresh install of Eclipse and pulled the same projects in but with the same issue.

Any guidance would be appreciated on how to resolve this!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this, having spent a solid day on it! Eventually I cloned the repository then remove all eclipse files from it (.project, .classpath, .metadata and .settings) and started again.